# BSTR to std::string (std::wstring) and vice versa

Tags: c++, string, com

While working with COM in C++ the strings are usually of `BSTR` data type. Someone can use `BSTR` wrapper like `CComBSTR` or MS's `CString`. But because I can't use ATL or MFC in MinGW compiler, is there standard code snippet to convert `BSTR` to `std::string` (or `std::wstring`) and vice versa?

Are there also some non-MS wrappers for `BSTR` similar to `CComBSTR`?

### Update

Thanks to everyone who helped me out in any way! Just because no one has addressed the issue on conversion between `BSTR` and `std::string`, I would like to provide here some clues on how to do it.

Below are the functions I use to convert `BSTR` to `std::string` and `std::string` to `BSTR` respectively:

```
std::string ConvertBSTRToMBS(BSTR bstr)
{
    int wslen = ::SysStringLen(bstr);
    return ConvertWCSToMBS((wchar_t*)bstr, wslen);
}

std::string ConvertWCSToMBS(const wchar_t* pstr, long wslen)
{
    int len = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pstr, wslen, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    std::string dblstr(len, '\0');
    len = ::WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0 /* no flags */,
                                pstr, wslen /* not necessary NULL-terminated */,
                                &dblstr[0], len,
                                NULL, NULL /* no default char */);

    return dblstr;
}

BSTR ConvertMBSToBSTR(const std::string& str)
{
    int wslen = ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0 /* no flags */,
                                      str.data(), str.length(),
                                      NULL, 0);

    BSTR wsdata = ::SysAllocStringLen(NULL, wslen);
    ::MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0 /* no flags */,
                          str.data(), str.length(),
                          wsdata, wslen);
    return wsdata;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `std::string` instead of `std::wstring` on Windows?

Comment: Yes, `std::wstring` will go well too! Question updated, thanks for your comment on this!

Comment: Why is there a wstring on windows?

Comment: @notbad.jpeg : Because in VC++ `wchar_t` is two bytes and Windows' native encoding is USC-2 (or UTF-16LE depending on who you ask). So, `wstring` is the natural way to hold a string without converting to/from the native encoding on Windows.

Comment: Windows' native encoding switched from UCS-2 to UTF-16LE in Windows 2000.  There is no "depending on who you ask" about it.

Comment: @Remy : Thanks, news to me and explains a lot. :-]

Comment: Don't you need to free wsdata in ConvertMBSToBSTR after use?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`BSTR` to `std::wstring`:

```
// given BSTR bs
assert(bs != nullptr);
std::wstring ws(bs, SysStringLen(bs));
```

`std::wstring` to `BSTR`:

```
// given std::wstring ws
assert(!ws.empty());
BSTR bs = SysAllocStringLen(ws.data(), ws.size());
```

---

Doc refs:

1. [`std::basic_string<typename CharT>::basic_string(const CharT*, size_type)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)
2. [`std::basic_string<>::empty() const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty)
3. [`std::basic_string<>::data() const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)
4. [`std::basic_string<>::size() const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size)
5. [`SysStringLen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65e792af-f8a8-4cdc-a279-494bba59394a%28vs.85%29)
6. [`SysAllocStringLen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f98bff39-bc5f-4a81-85d7-d5228e20fbc8%28VS.85%29)

Comment: Won't this fail if `bs` contains null?

Comment: @MooingDuck : Assuming you mean an embedded null character, then no – that's why the constructor taking a length is used instead of the one only taking a `wchar_t const*`. `SysStringLen` handles embedded nulls, unlike e.g. `wcslen`.

Comment: @ildjam I'm sorry if this is a rookie question, but I started doing "go to definition" on `BSTR` (you'll need to run VS as admin) and `BSTR` seems to be no more than a `wchar_t*`. On the other hand, I also found [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221240(v=vs.85).aspx) which, as you say, says that this constructor can handle embedded null characters. How can this constructor find the length of a `BSTR` if all it contains is a pointer to `wchar_t`?

Comment: @HerrKaputt : Because BSTRs are allocated on a special heap that retains the length of the allocation, and allows that length to be queried given a BSTR.

Comment: `NULL` is a **valid** state for `BSTR`, it is equivalent to an empty string. So the code should perhaps be `std::wstring(bs ? bs : L"");`

Comment: @M.M : COM considers a null string equivalent to an empty string, but IME, programmers do not. I intentionally had the code treat them differently; IMO, the possibility of null `BSTR`s should be represented via `boost::optional<>` or somesuch, not via invisible semantics that contributed heavily to COM's considerable Pain List™ to begin with.

Comment: @M.M : "*`BSTR` are null-terminated (as well as length-counted) so `std::wstring(bs)` works too.*" `std::wstring(bs)` does not support embedded null-characters, my code does – this was intentional. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn OK. Being permissive in what one accepts is often a good idea. Good point about embedded nulls

Comment: @M.M : Embedded nulls are unfortunately quite common on Windows, as the Windows Shell often uses nulls as delimiters and double-nulls as terminators. :-[ This usually leads to using `std::vector<wchar_t>` + algorithms rather than `std::wstring` in shell code, as it's more obvious how to handle these obtuse values; or rather, because dealing with them as string-typed objects appears highly non-idiomatic/scary.

Comment: This is not about personal preference: `NULL` **is** a valid `BSTR`, and your conversion code needs to be prepared for it. This is part of the documented contract for `BSTR`s. Otherwise you'll have to add a disclaimer, saying: *"Converts most `BSTR`s to `std::wstring`!"*

Comment: @IInspectable : It's not handled here because it's not obvious how it should be handled. I made a pointed note of it so the reader knows it needs to be addressed somehow, but there is no single correct semantic thus it would only confuse a useful answer.

Comment: There is no confusion about semantics. A `NULL` `BSTR` is semantically identical to an empty `BSTR`. That maps easily to a `std::wstring`. Constructing an empty `std::wstring` is the single correct and obvious conversion for a `NULL` `BSTR`.

Comment: @IInspectable : A `NULL` `BSTR` _can be_ semantically identical to an empty `BSTR`, because the runtime _allows_ for that, but literally every real codebase I've ever seen does **not** treat them semantically identically. If one wants to go that route, then the solution is obvious and I won't be motivated to edit it into my answer; and in the (IMO, likely) event that one _doesn't_ want to treat `NULL` and empty the same, they'll have to encode that however they see fit, which again, I can't predict. In any case, your point is valid, but sufficiently covered by my answer as-is.

Comment: @ildjarn see point 1 of the [first list here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/12/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics/).  It would be a bug if a codebase treated a null BSTR differently to an empty one.

Answer (score 11):

You could also do this

```
#include <comdef.h>

BSTR bs = SysAllocString("Hello");
std::wstring myString = _bstr_t(bs, false); // will take over ownership, so no need to free
```

or std::string if you prefer

EDIT: if your original string contains multiple embedded \0 this approach will not work.

Comment: This answer is not correct and will give you incorrect results if your string contains NULL characters.

Comment: In that case it is a problem with _bstr_t although I have never had any problems with that.

Comment: It's only a problem of `_bstr_t` in so far that it's a bit missleading. It just implicitly casts to `wchar_t*`. It never claims that that points to a null-terminated string. It's when you pass that value to the `std::wstring` constructor that you create the problem. It's just as wrong as `std::wstring otherstring = something(); std::wstring mystring = otherstring.c_str()`.

Comment: The example I gave is not wrong, however as you point out if the BSTR contains multiple \0 it will not work. No surprise there, the worst that can happen is a truncated string.

Answer (score 11):

There is a c++ class called `_bstr_t`.  It has useful methods and a collection of overloaded operators.

For example, you can easily assign from a `const wchar_t *` or a `const char *` just doing `_bstr_t bstr = L"My string";`  Then you can convert it back doing `const wchar_t * s = bstr.operator const wchar_t *();`.  You can even convert it back to a regular char `const char * c = bstr.operator char *();`  You can then just use the `const wchar_t *` or the `const char *` to initialize a new `std::wstring` oe `std::string`.

Comment: Good answer! `std::string str = _bstr_t(theBSTR);` Simples!

Answer (score 4):

Simply pass the BSTR directly to the wstring constructor, it is compatible with a wchar_t*:

```
BSTR btest = SysAllocString(L"Test");
assert(btest != NULL);
std::wstring wtest(btest);
assert(0 == wcscmp(wtest.c_str(), btest));
```

Converting BSTR to std::string requires a conversion to char* first.  That's lossy since BSTR stores a utf-16 encoded Unicode string.  Unless you want to encode in utf-8.  You'll find helper methods to do this, as well as manipulate the resulting string, in the ICU library.

Comment: That truncates any strings containing null characters, even though `BSTR` and `std::wstring` can both store them correctly.

Comment: Also fails if `btest` represents `null`

Comment: Ugh, never avoid an opportunity to have an unexpected null crash your program.