# Conversion from _bstr_t to std::string

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion

I am simply trying to convert _bstr_t into std::string..

I found a post on this issue ([LINK](http://bytecrunchers.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/converting-from-_bstr_t-to-other-string-types/)), and did exactly as described, but it is raising exception..

This is what I did:

```
_bstr_t BString;
std::string STDString((char *) BString);
```

And I get this error:

```
0CxC00000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000
```

Specifically, after looking at the call stack, error in iosfwd.h:

```
static size_t __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL length(const _Elem *_First)
    {   // find length of null-terminated string
    return (*_First == 0 ? 0
        : _CSTD strlen(_First));
    }
```

What is the right way to convert _bstr_t to std::string..?

Thanks

Comment: @MooingDuck Just edited the code.. yes it is _bstr_t

Comment: Note that `BString` probably uses UTF16 internally, and so the `char*` overload will use the current locale to choose a byte encoding, probably CP-1252, resulting in some characters being unable to be converted properly.

Comment: Either the post you linked to is full of crap, or compiling with `/clr` somehow makes the code in there work. A `_bstr_t` is a wrapper around a COM `BSTR`, which stores the length of the string in the first 4 bytes. So a cast is not going to do the job. Edit: Ah, I see how it works ... `_bstr_t` defines [implicit conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btdzb8eb.aspx) to `char *` and `whcar_t *`.

Comment: @Praetorian Oops, I misread and retracted the close vote. Again: Possible duplicate of [BSTR to std::string (std::wstring) and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284524/bstr-to-stdstring-stdwstring-and-vice-versa?lq=1)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Every answer on that page has the same bug as this question is encountering.  Since no answer on that page answers this question, I hesitate to close this as a dupe of that.  Maybe once that page has a better answer.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yup, you're right. None of the answers handles NULL or empty `bstr_t` values correctly.

Answer (score 4):

`BString` can hold a `null` value, wheras `std::string` cannot, so you'll have to account for this.

```
const char* buf = BString;
int bstrlen = BString.length();
std::string STDString( buf?buf:"", bstrlen);
```

Note that BString probably uses UTF16 internally, and so the char* overload will use the current locale to choose a byte encoding, probably CP-1252, resulting in some characters being unable to be converted properly.

Comment: No need for the initial cast in the conditional.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I hadn't tested, but since it has four implicit conversions that are valid in a boolean context, I figured not having the cast would result in a "ambiguity" compiler error.

Comment: @KonradRudolph "`error C2440: '?' : cannot convert from '_bstr_t' to 'bool'      Ambiguous user-defined-conversion`" http://rextester.com/HPES3175