# Pipe BSTR into wstringstream?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, bstr

There's a tried and tested answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6284978/197229) how to convert `BSTR` -> `std::wstring`. But I want to include the BSTR in a `wstringstream` I am building up.

Clearly I can do (a bit contrived as a MRE):

```
std::wstring proc(BSTR bStr)
{
 std::wstringstream ss;
 std::wstring ws(bStr, SysStringLen(bStr));
 
 ss << "The string is: " << ws; 
 return ss.str();
}
```

But is there a way to avoid creating the temporary `ws` object and pipe `bStr` in directly?

Comment: `ss.write(bStr, SysStringLen(bStr))`?

Comment: `ss << "The string is: " << bStr` should work, unless it's not null terminated (it's rare but technically possible).

Comment: thanks @SimonMourier that's the sort of thing I was unsure about - a quick test that seems fine but leaves edge cases (like what if `bStr` is empty/null?)

Comment: As long as you cast or use it normally, a BSTR *is* an array of bytes, ie: a wchar_t* (or LP(C)WSTR in Windows parlance). Usually, these bytes encode a unicode string. And usually they are null terminated.

Comment: @SimonMourier by definition, a non-null BSTR is always null-terminated, and any API that deals with BSTR memory would expect a terminator to be present. So, how would it be "technically possible" to have a BSTR without a terminator?

Comment: @Remy lebeau, you can put anything you want in a BSTR and all marshalers will work fine since the size is declared https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-sysallocstringbytelen#remarks *"If psz is Null, a string of the requested length is allocated, but not initialized. The string psz can contain embedded null characters, and does not need to end with a Null"*

Comment: @SimonMourier the *data* does not need a terminating null, but the *bstr* will still have one present. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr

Comment: @RemyLebeau - what I mean is if you do this `SysAllocStringByteLen("hello", 5);` and push it into a wstringstream, you have a potential buffer overflow/crash since the string is not really null terminated in a wide char sense (the added wide char null will be unaligned with the string as a wide char string)

Comment: @SimonMourier perhaps, but on the other hand `wstringstream` is meant for handling wide strings not binary data, but `SysAllocStringByteLen()` is meant for handling binary data not wide strings.  So that would be a data mismatch on the caller's part.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - 1) that's technically possible, as I said, and 2) that's a potential security issue, whoever the caller is.

Answer (score 2):

`BSTR` is just a typedef for `wchar_t*` as far as the compiler is concerned (it is just *allocated* differently at runtime than a normal `wchar_t` C string).

And by definition, a non-empty `BSTR` is always null-terminated (even though it is also length-prefixed).

So, unless your string has embedded nul characters in it (which is possible), you can just use the normal `operator<<` for wide strings. Just watch out for the case where the `BSTR` is a null pointer, which will exhibit *undefined behavior* for the operator.

Try this:

```
std::wstring proc(BSTR bStr)
{
 std::wstringstream ss; 
 ss << L"The string is: ";
 if (bStr) ss << bStr; 
 return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: The edge case is when `bStr == nullptr`, which represents the empty string. See https://ericlippert.com/2003/09/12/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics/ Use `std::wstring_view(bStr, SysStringLen(bStr))` which fixes both the `nullptr` and embedded null problems.

Answer (score 1):

> [I]s there a way to avoid creating the temporary `ws` object and pipe `bStr` in directly?

Yes, of course!

A [`BSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr) is a `wchar_t*` in disguise that upholds all requirements to make [`basic_ostream::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) happy: It is guaranteed to be either a `nullptr` or a pointer to a sequence of `CharT` values, terminated by a `NUL` character.

Writing

```cpp
    ss << "The string is: " << bstr;
```

is perfectly valid.

Albeit, doing so ignores acknowledging two edge cases where a `BSTR` is more lenient than a conventional C-style string:

- It can contain `NUL` characters as part of the sequence, leading to truncation
- It could be a `nullptr` producing an implementation-defined string in the output stream

Neither is desirable, and either issue is addressed by introducing the `std::wstring` `ws` as an intermediary. This isn't something we can give up. With the intermediary a non-negotiable requirement, the question is: Can we get `std::wstring`'s services without paying the price of a (needless) allocation?

As of C++17, we can. The tool is called [`std::wstring_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), capable of producing "modern" dangling pointers as well as solving the issue at hand:

```cpp
    ss << "The string is: " << std::wstring_view(bstr, ::SysStringLen(bStr));
```

This brings back the `std::wstring` niceties without a price tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this as an answer even though it should be a comment (to your own post and the other responses), and it doesn't actually address your question (others correctly have), but just an (off-topic) FYI that a BSTR is not technically a "wchar_t" pointer. It's actually an OLECHAR pointer but since OLECHAR maps to "wchar_t" on modern Windows you can effectively treat it that way (and likely get away with it forever at this point, at least on Windows).

It's therefore a pedantic (really moot) issue at this point (for a very long time now), but to be technically correct (and old-school developers in this stuff often will be), you should be explicitly converting your BSTR to a "wchar_t" pointer (or even TCHAR pointer on Windows) before treating it that way (as a "wchar_t" pointer or whatever TCHAR is for those still using it, normally "wchar_t" as well).

How you do this is off-topic here (ancient MFC has ancient macros for it as one possible way - search for "*OLE conversion macros*" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn059-using-mfc-mbcs-unicode-conversion-macros?view=msvc-170)), but again, in reality you can safely (usually) get away with just treating it as a "wchar_t" pointer on (modern) Windows as you're now doing (since going through the hoops of explicitly converting it to a "wchar_t" pointer on modern Windows will just treat a BSTR as a "wchar_t" pointer anyway - no conversion necessary and the above MFC macros handle things this way).

If you ever need to target an environment where OLECHAR doesn't map to "wchar_t" however, religiously doing the conversion now will correctly handle things in the future (that's what the conversion is for), compared to how you're now handling it (though most do treat a BSTR as a "wchar_t" pointer these days, though in the context that it's still a BSTR so needs to be treated that way, and even Microsoft itself treats it as a "wchar_t" pointer in some of its own sample code and documentation, but it's still an OLECHAR pointer nevertheless so such code will break if you ever target an environment where OLECHAR doesn't map to "wchar_t").

Comment: An `OLECHAR` has **always** been a `WCHAR` on Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable In 32-bit Windows that's true (assuming the obsolete OLE2ANSI isn't #defined - not normally of course), though not in 16-bit Windows but that obviously has no relevance anymore either. OLECHAR is not technically a "wchar_t" however so purists would argue it's cleaner to treat it as the opaque character type it really is (not a "wchar_t" even though it always maps to that in Win32)

Comment: I see, so in 16-bit Windows, `OLECHAR` was an alias for `CHAR`. This means that [Remy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77496077/1889329) may silently do what wasn't intended, while [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77498346/1889329) won't (it will not compile for 16-bit Windows).

Comment: This is another way of saying that judiciously confining support and actively preventing unsupported scenarios from compiling is a compelling alternative to *"religiously doing the conversion"*. The alternative is compelling since *"doing the conversion"* is not something you can get right and have it be correct in the future. Multibyte character strings represented as `char*` are a mess, with several competing character encodings. No religion (or sorcery) is going to alleviate this.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow what you said, and don't want to get into an off-topic treatise about the situation, but what I posted is endorsed by the lead authors of the ATL at Microsoft (such as Jim Springfield, who IIRC was the primary developer of the ATL). I'd have to dig my old manuals up for the actual citations (possibly the book "ATL Internals" which was the bible for ATL development at the time, though I haven't read it in many years).

Comment: What I'm saying is this: When you have a `BSTR`, the only *safe* path forward is to assume that `OLECHAR` is a `WCHAR` and reject any other incarnation. Once you get into the conversion business (which implies that `OLECHAR` is a `CHAR`), you'll inevitably have to guess the encoding. Things were simpler in the early ATL days, with `CP_ACP` being a safe bet. Should `OLECHAR` ever become a `CHAR` again, then `CP_ACP` certainly won't be a reasonable choice, and *"doing the conversion now will correctly handle things in the future"* doesn't hold much water.